# How to change error type from Never to Error in Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

```
notificationCenterPublisher = NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: context)
            .map { (notification) -> (CoreDataContextObserverState) in
                self.handleContextObjectDidChangeNotification(notification: notification)
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

I have the method handleContextObjectDidChangeNotification doing the mapping.

Right now notificationCenterPublisher is of type `AnyPublisher<CoreDataContextObserverState, Never>`

But I want to make it `AnyPublisher<CoreDataContextObserverState, Error>` and have handleContextObjectDidChangeNotification have some way of indicating an error has occured.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always change the failure type of a `Publisher` using [`setFailureType(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204753-setfailuretype) when the failure type is `Never`:

```
notificationCenterPublisher = NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: context)
    .map { (notification) -> (CoreDataContextObserverState) in
        self.handleContextObjectDidChangeNotification(notification: notification)
    }
    .setFailureType(to: Error.self) <------------------- add this
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

You can let your `handle` method throw an error and turn that into a publisher failure using [`tryMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204772-trymap):

```
notificationCenterPublisher = NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: context)
    .tryMap { try self.handleContextObjectDidChangeNotification($0) }
  // ^^^^^^   ^^^
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

This will also change the publisher's failure type to `Error`.

Comment: It's not the only way, but it's probably the right way for your use case. Another way is to [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204712-flatmap) to a [`Fail`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail) or a [`Result.Publisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/publisher).